# When there is already a window.load==function(){} how to add keyDown event for a canvas

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, onload, keydown

I used some JS API to make some charts. In the code there is already `window.onload = function (){}`, now I want to have keydown event for a canvas. Does anybody know where to add the code? It seems pretty silly but I just cannot get information about the window.onload's effect for the js action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DOM2 handler instead:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { /*...your code here...*/}, false);
```

On IE8 and earlier, you have to handle the fact that they don't have it:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() { /*...your code here...*/}, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", function() { /*...your code here...*/});
}
```

DOM2 handlers sit alongside the old DOM0 handlers, without interfering with them. The big advantage they offer is that you can have multiple handlers for the same event, so this issue (of there already being a handler) doesn't come up.

---

Side note: The `load` event on `window` happens *really late* in the page load process, after all external resources have complete loaded (or failed to). 99% of the time, it's [better to just put your code in a `script` at the end of the `body`](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), just before the closing `</body>` tag, like this:

```
<!-- ...content... -->
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you don't need to hook the `load` event at all, because all of the DOM elements defined by the markup above already exist. Just have your code run immediately.